# How to work with a lis of data.frame and many scenario (TRUE/FALSE)

Tags: r, list, intervals

I have a list of 689 `data.frame` name `DF`. Each data.frame have a different name and many columns. For this question, just the columns `$AGE` is interesting.

The first thing a want to do is find the max of the `$AGE` columns for each data.frame. Whit this code it’s ok a can find the max for each data.frame

```
AV<- sapply(DF, function(x) max(x$AGE, na.rm=TRUE))
```

It’s after this code I don’t know what to do. So first, I have to scenario possible to TEST if the scenarios are true or false

1. If the max is <150, 60% of my value (of the columns df$AGE) is in a interval of +or – 70 of the max (interval = max-70,max+70)
2. If the max is >150, 60% of my value (of the columns df$AGE) is in a interval of +or – 40 of the max (interval = max-40,max+40)

For all `data.frame` that for one of the scenario the result is `TRUE`, I want to keep the result somewhere. If it’s `FALSE`,I want to go to scenario 3 and 4 that the same thing of 1 and 2 but with less value. I’m a little loss especially whit how to work whit a list of data.frame

Thank

Comment: You could explain the scenarios a little better with possibly an example?

Comment: i edit my my question but i can do example because i dont know how to do that

Comment: Don't worry about your list yet. Focus on a single data frame. Write a function that does your test performs the correct actions for a single data frame, returning the result you want to keep. Then, when that is done, you just run `lapply(DF, your_function)`.

Comment: For an example, [here is a nice guide on how to make a reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Either simulate a *little bit* of data, or `dput()` a *little bit* of example data. In this case, I would say 2 example data frames, one that meets condition 1, and one that doesn't, would be appropriate. Maybe with 5-10 sample rows each.

Comment: Thank but what a d'ont understand is how to do my condition. With if...else statement ? or something like that : if (max<150 & 60% og my value is in a interval of + or - 30 of the max) ?